# Listar dados em um DropDown relacionado ao resultado de outro DropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, dropdown

Estou refazendo essa pergunta, pois não deve ter ficado muito clara.
O que quero, é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Escolher um restaurante no DropDown, e no dropdown seguinte, listar os horários que foram cadastrados por aquele restaurante.

Aqui está o meu Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EscolhaID,UsuarioID,HorarioID,RestauranteID")] EscolhaReserva escolhaReserva)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
            escolhaReserva.UsuarioID = id;
            escolhaReserva.Usuario = db.Usuarios.Find(id);

            db.EscolhaReservas.Add(escolhaReserva);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");                             
        }

        ViewBag.HorarioID = new SelectList(db.Horarios, "HorarioID", "HorarioFinal", escolhaReserva.HorarioID);
        ViewBag.RestauranteID = new SelectList(db.Restaurantes, "RestauranteID", "Nome", escolhaReserva.RestauranteID);
        ViewBag.UsuarioID = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "UsuarioID", "Nome", escolhaReserva.UsuarioID);
        return View(escolhaReserva);
    }
```

Quero fazer com que, ao clicar no DropDown de Restaurante, ele exiba os respectivos horários. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Allan refazer a pergunta não vai lhe trazer a resposta e provavelmente sua pergunta sera marcada como duplicata. Sua outra pergunta também não esta muito clara, vc precisa ser mais objetivo e mostrar como esta tetando exibir os horários do restaurante. Seria interessante se vc posta-se seu código.

Comment: pelo oque entendi, cada restaurante tem seus horários vc quer de acordo com o restaurante que a pessoa escolher mostrar os horários referentes é isso ?

Comment: edite o poste colocando como esta suas tabelas, pra ficar mais fácil de te ajudar

Comment: Pronto. Editei.